# CORS Issue with AJAX redirect to SAML 2.0 Identity Provider

Tags: javascript, ajax, apache, cors, saml-2.0

I have an Angular web application that I'm hosting on an Apache web server that's configured with the [mod_auth_mellon](https://github.com/UNINETT/mod_auth_mellon) module. With mod_auth_mellon, my Apache server acts as a Service Provider with a SAML 2.0 Identity Provider (iDP), for which I have an established Relying Party Trust.

Once authenticated, the web application will fire off an AJAX call in the background every minute. This call goes through a reverse proxy that I've set up on the Apache server.

**The typical browser flow:** Once the Apache mellon session (MellonSessionLength) expires, any request going through Apache will redirect back to the SAML iDP to re-negotate. Assuming I'm still authenticated with the iDP, mellon will establish a new session and automatically redirect me back to my original destination. Normally, this re-negotiation is an extra request or two that happens seamlessly behind the scenes.

**The problem:** The mellon session will typically expire when my background AJAX request is firing, which redirects that request back to the iDP. On the AJAX request back to the iDP, the browser is giving a CORS error and the response includes a generic log-in page (rather than my redirect destination). My (Apache) requests should appear to originate from the same domain as the iDP, but not the same subdomain (but, in reality, they are two different servers): *(mywebapp.mydomain.com vs. idp.mydomain.com)*. If I simply copy the request URL into the browser bar manually, the re-negotiation happens without a problem.

**Question #1:** As far as I can tell, it's the browser that's blocking this request. Is this an Apache configuration issue?

**Question #2:** If I can fix the CORS issue, will the JavaScript be able to successfully interpret the response from the iDP such that mellon establishes a new session? I've been reading some articles that give me some pause - some people talk about potentially having to embed a hidden iFrame on the page to handle the iDP response prior to redirecting to the destination URL.

Comment: As far as resolving the CORS error, yes, it is the browser blocking — but to be clear, it’s the browser blocking your frontend JavaScript from accessing the *response* from the server. It’s not the browser blocking the *request*. The way CORS works is that browser makes the request and gets the response back, but only allows your frontend JavaScript code to access the response if the response includes the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header. And server-side CORS configuration never causes a server to block a request; instead it only affects what response headers the server sends back.

Comment: So as far as your question about whether it’s an Apache configuration issue, the answer is Yes. Specifically, if you configure Apache such that you ensure it’s always sending back the Access-Control-Allow-Origin in all cases, then the browser will allow your frontend JavaScript to access the response, and the CORS error will go away. And if the nature of the response is such that it can be consumed and handled by frontend JavaScript code without, say, causing an additional cross-origin request to some other third-party server that isn’t CORS-enabled, then things will just work.

Comment: @sideshowbarker I've done some additional testing and it seems that the browser is indeed blocking the response from the iDP. For kicks, I tried disabling CORS by starting Chrome in --disable-web-security mode and I was able to see the real response from the iDP - but it is an HTML response, meant to be interpreted by the browser to automatically POST a new SAMLResponse back to the /mellon/login endpoint. The AJAX call won't handle this.

Comment: It's possible that, without the CORS issue, I can parse the HTML response and perform an AJAX POST containing the SAMLResponse to /mellon/login, but it seems that my iDP doesn't support sending that CORS header back.

Comment: We are facing similar issue. We're you able to resolve it?

Thanks CP

Comment: @Chintan Nope. For now, we have just extended the TTL of our sessions to 24 hours to reduce the frequency of the issue.

Comment: @littleK,  so I fixed issue in different way. Since Idp was not sending cors header back, we are extending mellon session as user browse through angular application. Each angular service call first call /mellon/sessionRefresh endpoints which extends mellon session from current time + mellSessionLength time and returns 200 else 440 http status code. With this, mellon will not go to Idp for token check and ajax/angular service calls work.  Mellon/sessionRefresh is custom code I added to mellon module just to extends mellon session.